# How to cast Func<T, object> to Func<Exception, object>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-conversion

I would like to create a dictionary to store exceptions and formatters for that exceptions.

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception, ApiErrorResponse>>
```

I can add them directly to the dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception, ApiErrorResponse>> _exceptionFormatters =
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception, ApiErrorResponse>>
            {
                {
                    typeof(ValidationException),
                    ex =>
                    {
                        var e = ex as ValidationException;
                        return new ApiErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity, e.Errors);
                    }
                },
                {
                    typeof(NotFoundException),
                    ex =>
                    {
                        var e = ex as NotFoundException;
                        return new ApiErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, e.Message);
                    }
                }
            };
```

But I would like to do it with generic `AddExceptionFormatter` method

```
public static void AddExceptionFormatter<T>(Func<T, ApiErrorResponse> Value) where T : Exception
{
    if (_exceptionFormatters.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        _exceptionFormatters[typeof(T)] = (Func<Exception, ApiErrorResponse>)Value;
    else
        _exceptionFormatters.Add(typeof(T), (Func<Exception, ApiErrorResponse>)Value);
}
```

Here is how I invoke it.

```
AddExceptionFormatter<NotFoundException>(ex =>
            {
                return new ApiErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.NotFoundException,
                    nameof(NotFoundException),
                    ex.Message);
            });
```

But unfortunately I'm getting
`` Unable to cast object of type 'System.Func`2[NotFoundException,ApiErrorResponse]' to type 'System.Func`2[System.Exception,ApiErrorResponse]'. ``

Any Ideas how can I cast my `Func<,>`?

Comment: Use `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey`. It won't help with your current problem, but it will be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary is storing "functions that take any `Exception`s", but you are giving the dictionary a "function that take a specific `Exception` that is `T`". Clearly, a "function that take a specific `Exception` that is `T`" is not a kind of "functions that take any `Exception`s".

To see why this can break, suppose:

```
AddExceptionFormatter<NotFoundException>(x => x.Foo);
```

where `Foo` is a property that `NotFoundException` has, and is of type `ApiErrorResponse`.

Now if I do this naughty thing:

```
_exceptionFormatters[typeof(NotFoundException)](new Exception())
```

Clearly, this passes the type check, since I can pass an `Exception` to `Func<Exception, ApiErrorResponse>`, but `Exception` doesn't actually have a `Foo` property! This is why you are not allowed to cast.

The fundamental problem here is that you can't guarantee to the compiler that "if `typeof(X)` is one of the dictionary's keys, `_exceptionFormatters[typeof(X)]` will be of type `Func<X, ApiErrorResponse>`". C#'s type system isn't strong enough to support that.

You need to decide what you want to happen when someone do something like the aforementioned naughty behaviour. Suppose you want an exception to be thrown, you can use a lambda:

```
public static void AddExceptionFormatter<T>(Func<T, ApiErrorResponse> Value) where T : Exception
{
    _exceptionFormatters[typeof(T)] = x => Value((T)x);
}
```

This will cause an `InvalidCastException` to be thrown. You could of course do something more fancy in the lambda:

```
x => {
    if (x is T t) {
        return Value(t);
    } else {
        throw new YourCustomException("some custom message");
    }
}
```

Comment: `_exceptionFormatters` will be private so no one have access to that and only way to add formatters would be to use `Add..` method :) so your first solution is enough for me I guess :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that such a cast is possible because the two function declarations are entirely unrelated, as far as the compiler is concerned.

You can try to change the declaration of the AddExceptionFormatter to

```
public static void AddExceptionFormatter<T>(Func<Exception, ApiErrorResponse> Value) where T : Exception
```

Then there is no need to cast anything.

You might also be able to do something with an interface to invoke the formatting function and a generic implementation. Though that is more complex and may not be as performant. I did not try to compile he code below, so treat it more like a guide.

```
interface IExceptionFormatter
{
    ApiErrorResponse Format(Exception)
} 

class ExceptionFormatter<T> : IExceptionFormatter
{
    private Func<T, ApiErrorResponse> _formatDelegate;
    public ExceptionFormatter(Func<T, ApiErrorResponse> formatDelegate)
    {
        _formatDelegate = formatDelegate;
    }

    public ApiErrorResponse Format(Exception ex)
    {
        return _formatDelegate(ex);
    }
}

public static void AddExceptionFormatter<T>(Func<T, ApiErrorResponse> Value) where T : Exception
{
    Type templateType= typeof(ExceptionFormatter<>);
    Type[] args = {typeof(T)};
    Type desiredType = templateType.MakeGenericType(args);
    if (_exceptionFormatters.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        _exceptionFormatters[typeof(T)] = Activator.CreateInstance(desiredType, Value);
    else
        _exceptionFormatters.Add(typeof(T), Activator.CreateInstance(desiredType, Value);
}
```

Then you dictionary can contain the specific implementations for various exception types.

Dictionary<Type, IExceptionFormatter> _exceptionFormatters

Comment: Yes, but with that I will need to cast `Exception` to specific one (to get access to additional properties) once adding a formatter.

Comment: I have expanded my answer some with other options